# OnCreateOptionsMenu called from abstract class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have abstract class for my app. `AbstractToolbarActivity` and extended class `AboutActivity`. And in my abstract activity I override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu)
    return true
}
```

Its Kotlin.

And i override this function in extended activity `AboutActivity`:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menu?.clear()
    return false
}
```

But when i start my `AboutActivity` it calls the function from the parent class. I override it, so why is it calling the implementation in the abstract class? How I can clear menu items?

Comment: Are you sure this is the real problem, which function being called?  Did you log from the functions or add something else that can verify which is being called?

Comment: Also, you can omit the `?` on the `Menu?` if you are sure it is always passed as a non null value.  Overridden functions are allowed to further define the nullability of a Java method.

Comment: I debug it. Yeah, function from extended activity is not calling.